# Creating expansion file will also effects static array reference?

Tags: android, arrays, video, apk-expansion-files

I am working on an Android Project, Project based on Training. I have provided 64 videos for the training sessions according to the level. All videos are inside raw folder and and i am using these videos by specifying paths with a name of video in static `String[]` array. Now i have two questions.

1. My apk size is 138MB and how do i create expansion file
2. Will creating the expansion file destroy my static `String[]` array video link because according to the document i have to move all files into separate file.